# In First Question filters, it suggests 14.04

Tags: bug, tags, review

In the filters of "First Question" queue, it is suggesting 14.04.

[image: Filter Tags placeholder]

Comment: I think that's probably not a bug, but a dumb AI and a missing feature. We should disallow any questions with outdated tags, and exclude outdated tags from the tag suggesting system.

Comment: This isn't very useful as a bug report because it doesn't explain the problem at all. What is 14.04, and why is this a bug? (Emoji's comment explains it a bit better, but that info should be in the post itself.)

Comment: A possibly semi-related MSE post: [How are "Suggested Tags" chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/206907/335251) That said, I don't think it quite addresses this issue, because the tag filters aren't suggesting a tag for any given question... I'm guessing it might be related to [popular tags](https://askubuntu.com/tags?tab=popular), though – [tag:14.04] is the 4th most used tag on the site, and [tag:networking] is 2nd. ([tag:wireless] is down in 15th place, though.)

Comment: @V2Blast 14.04 is a (rather old and EOL) version of Ubuntu. We have tags for each Ubuntu version. The most recent (stable) version of Ubuntu is 22.04. The oldest on-topic version is 18.04. The theory is that by having question-askers tag their questions with their version of Ubuntu, some things are easier. Except... quite a few users see 14.04 there and think "Hey look, something's there. I guess I'll use it as a tag"... and this results in a decent amount of questions (wrongly) tagged as 14.04 when they should be tagged with the version of ubuntu the OP has, which is annoying (continued)

Comment: ... (continued) because then people comment "Hey, are you using Ubuntu 14.04, or something newer", because of the sheer amount of people just tagging their question as that because it is suggested even when they have a _far_ newer version of Ubuntu. And then the OP edits their question to fix it. But it happens often enough it is annoying, and it would be easier to not deal with this in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some comments have already mentioned, it's probably not a bug as it's just some selection of popular tags.

If something needs to be changed here, it should probably be a separate feature request.

Having said that, I think it's good to show outdated tags in the *First questions* queue. For example, if you filter on 14.04 and find questions about them, there's a high chance they will be off-topic (please don't robo-vote-to-close, though!).

When you're creating a new question, it shows different tags, but if I remember correctly, moderators have control over what to show there (or not show?).

[image: Tags when asking a question]